# Valor de Formulário não volta no Collective laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

O formulário na parte de edção, não aparece o valor vindo do banco de dados.
Todos os outros campos do formulário estão voltando o valor pego no banco de dados. 
Veja como estou fazendo:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
      {!! Form::label('departamento','Departamento', array('class'    =>  'control-label')) !!}
      {!! Form::select('departamento',[
            'null' =>  'Escolha uma Opção',
            'jeans'             =>  'Jeans', 'senhores e senhoras'      =>   'Senhores e Senhoras',
            'grupo de Louvor'   =>  'Grupo de Louvor', 'kids'           =>  'Kids',  
            'geral'             =>  'Geral',
            ],null,['class'  => 'form-control']) !!} 
</div>
```

Até onde eu sei, a opção passada no parâmetro do **Form::select()** o NULL, é onde volta os dados do banco. Mais não esta voltando. O que será que passar esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem bastante problemas em fazer assim, é melhor criar um `array` no seu `controller` e passar para a `View` ***exemplo***:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $departamentos[''] = 'Escolha uma Opção';
    $departamentos['jeans'] = 'Jeans';
    $departamentos['grupo de Louvor'] = 'Grupo de Louvor';
    //e assim por diante

    return view("nome da view")
            ->with('departamentos', $departamentos)
            ->with('id_departamento', id_departamento);
}
```

***Observação:*** *lembrando que para carregue esse `Form::select` precisa ser uma `array` chave e valor, como demostrado na `function edit`*

---

Olha a redução de código:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 {!! Form::label('departamento','Departamento', array('class'=>  'control-label')) !!}
 {!! Form::select('departamento', $departamentos, $id_departamento,
                ['class'=>'form-control']) 
      !!} 
</div>
```

O `select` só vai se posicionar no registro quando você passar `$id_departamento` para a `View`.

Só ratificando como deve passar:

> [`echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');`](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

- o primeiro parâmetro é o nome do `select`
- o segundo é o `array` **chave** e **valor**
- o terceiro parâmetro é o responsável em posicionar o `select`.

***Referencias***

- [Form select box {!!Form::select()!!}](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-select-box-formselect?page=1)
- [Drop-Down Lists](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma, mais não sabia que tinha jeito de fazer dessa forma Muito bom. Valeu